# "Classificado" é sinônimo de "confidencial"?

Tags: sinônimos

Em inglês, a palavra *classified* é traduzida como "confidencial". A palavra "classificado", no português, é também um sinônimo de "confidencial"? Um colega utilizou a palavra nesse contexto, afirmando que em português possuia o mesmo significado, mas suspeitei de que se tratava de um falso cognato. O único dicionário online ao qual consegui acesso, o Priberam (acredito que se trate de um dicionário de português de Portugal), [enumera](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/classificado) o significado de "confidencial" dentre os sinônimos de "classificado". Se a evidência do dicionário é suficiente, gostaria de saber se se trata de um americanismo, isto é, de que é uma adição recente à língua portuguesa, e não um significado "histórico".

<sub>Por favor, permitam-me saber se esta questão não é apropriada para o site; sou novo aqui no *Portuguese Language Stack Exchange.*</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Resumo**: parece tratar-se de um anglicismo semântico já dicionarizado que, pelo menos no Brasil, é pouco usado.

---

No sentido de confidencialidade, o termo em inglês, *classified*, indica a  classificação de informação em uma dada categoria de confidencialidade/segurança nacional, de acordo com o dano que sua divulgação poderia causar ao país.

Nunca encontrei a palavra "classificado" sendo usada com esse sentido no Brasil. Apenas "confidencial", "sigiloso", "secreto", etc. Os dicionários brasileiros [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/classificado/) e [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/classificado) não listam "confidencial" dentre seus significados, enquanto dicionários europeus, como a [Infopedia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/classificado) e o [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/classificado), o fazem. Por outro lado, em 2010, a professora Maria João Matos [menciona que](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/documentos-desclassificados/27485)

> Em nenhum dicionário português de referência encontrei esse significado [...] Já o dicionário brasileiro Houaiss acrescenta uma nova entrada ao termo classificado, que qualifica como «anglicismo semântico»

O que responde à pergunta sobre a origem desse uso do termo, ao mesmo tempo em que sugere um quadro em que esse sentido tornou-se aceitável mais cedo no Brasil, mas cujo uso difundiu-se mais rapidamente em Portugal.

Com relação ao vocabulário usado em leis, em Portugal a lei utiliza "classificado" no sentido de "confidencial", e.g., [Lei Orgânica 02/2014 - Regime do Segredo de Estado](http://www.pgdlisboa.pt/leis/lei_mostra_articulado.php?nid=2201&tabela=leis&ficha=1&pagina=1&so_miolo=), artigo 3.7c:

> Proibição de armazenamento de documentos e informações classificados fora dos locais ou equipamentos definidos para o efeito.

Enquanto uma busca rápida por leis similares no Brasil retorna o uso do termo apenas em documentos sobre acordos de compartilhamento de informações com outros países (como este [acordo com os EUA](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2015-2018/2016/decreto/D8694.htm)).

Comment: Resposta excelente e muito completa! Foi bom também ver as ocorrências legais da expressão. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Com espírito de opinião, digo que é melhor evitar *classificado* como confidencial/sigiloso e usar estes dois adjetivos como alternativas; já que tanto ocorre a confusão por aparentar particípio passado do verbo *classificar* quanto trata-se de um americanismo.

Comment: @William este é o mesmo sentimento que eu já tinha. No contexto da conversa que estava tendo com meu amigo, o contexto deixava claro o significado, bem como meu pequeno conhecimento de inglês. Em todo caso, é melhor mesmo evitar o uso desse termo nesse sentido.